# How to restart mouse tracking in X windows?

Tags: centos, mouse, vncserver, events

I'm on a Centos 4 32 bit machine and have connected from my MacBook via VNC to a `DISPLAY` created with `vncserver`.  All was working well for the past month, then suddenly today, the mouse stopped working inside the VNC client, but keyboard remains working and the display continues to refresh.  I quit the VNC client and restarted it, still the same issue.  I connected to a different VNC server and the mouse works fine.  I launched `xev` and see that no mouse events are being seen, just keyboard events are registering.

I really want to retain this session as I have long running test data inside emacs in it that is still running.  Is there some mouse process that I can restart to get mouse events working again?  I am able to create a new `vncserver` on the same machine and connect to it and successfully get mouse events working, so the mouse issue is specific to this one `vncserver`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to restart the window manager, for my version of Centos 4, Gnome 2 is desktop environment and the default window manager for Gnome 2 is [Metacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacity) which is restarted like this:

```
DISPLAY=myMachine:XX /usr/bin/metacity --sm-client-id=default1 --replace
```

Once the window manager is restarted, the mouse starts working again.